# Streaming live audio from audio interface over a local network via browser

Tags: python, http, flask, audio, webrtc

This is my first post so sorry if it’s worded wrong/ put in the wrong place.

I am currently designing a prototype product which has the ability to take an audio input (for example the master channel from a sound desk) through an audio interface, and then place it on a browser-based application for all devices on the local network to access, listen to and download.

Currently I believe the best way to do this would be via WebRTC hosted on a server, such as a Raspberry Pi or equivalent, where WebRTC is ran through Python Tornado/Flask in order to serve this to an HTTP page. I would like some advice on the best way to do this, or if you believe if there is a more efficient way to do this?

I was going to use the server to also act as a DHCP server as it will be for local environments only. Management features such as routing protocols, logging/debugging information and encryption handlers will also be displayed on this HTTP application.

I have attached a diagram of the topology that I am using, if I have not explained myself clearly.

Thanks.

[Network Topology Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qr0c.png)

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question?

Comment: [Recommendation questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) are considered off-topic on SO.

Comment: Is WebRTC the best technology to use for this design? Sorry if I was not clear